# closing a modal pop up

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a modal pop up that comes up when a hyperlink is clicked.. now i want to add a button withing the modal pop up to close it.. but i am not sure how to., i tried this

```
<ajaxToolKit:ModalPopupExtender ID="mPopup" runat="server" TargetControlID="HyperLink"
    PopupControlID="pnlItem" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" />
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlItem" Style="display: none;" CssClass="PopupStyle" Width="400">
    <div>
        <ucc:High ID="High" runat="server" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnClose" runat="server" Text="CLOSE" 
            OnClientClick="javascript:document.getElementById('btnClose').click();return false;" />
    </div>
</asp:Panel>
```

But its not working.. it throws js script issues.

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Can't you set the close button as a property on the modal popup?

Comment: Not sure why you got a down vote... This is a valid question.

Comment: sorry, i am a newbie .. can you explain, i can create a property and then what would i need to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a property called **CancelControlID**. More explanation is available at http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ModalPopup/ModalPopup.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
<ajaxToolKit:ModalPopupExtender ID="mPopUp" CancelControlID="btnClose" runat="server" TargetControlID="HyperLink2"
                           PopupControlID="pnlItem" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" />
                           <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlItem" Style="display: none;" CssClass="PopupStyle"
                            Width="400">
                         <div>
                               <ucc:High ID="High" runat="server" />
                               <asp:Button ID="btnClose" runat="server" Text="Close" OnClientClick="javascript:document.getElementById('btnClose').click();return false;" />
                         </div>
                         </asp:Panel>
```